# Codeigniter session flashdata and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, session, message

I'm using codeigniter flashdata to set messages after a redirect. Well if I'm using it without ajax, everything just works fine. If I echo out messages received with flashdata it still works like it should BUT if I refresh with F5 once, I still see that message. Flashdata gets cleared after the second refresh... How can I resolve this?

This is, what my function looks like:

```
public static function message()
{
    if ( ! empty(self::$message['message']))
    {
        // build message
        $message = '<div class="alert alert-' . self::$message['type'] . '"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>' . self::$message['heading'] . '</strong>' . self::$message['message'] . '</div>';

        // clear static message array
        self::$message = array();

        // return static message
        return $message;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( class_exists('CI_Session'))
        {
            // get flash message
            $message = self::$CI->session->flashdata('message');

            // clear flash data
            self::$CI->session->set_flashdata('message', null);

            // process flash message
            if ( ! empty($message))
            {
                // slice flashdata into single parts
                $message = explode('::', $message);

                // return flash message
                return '<div class="alert alert-' . $message[0] . '"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>' . $message[1] . '</strong>' . $message[2] . '</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: F5 + ctrl clears the cache. Where F5 only refreshes and dont lose session data

Answer (score 1):

Form the [CI Manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> If you find that you need to preserve a flashdata variable through an additional request, you can do so using the keep_flashdata() function.
>
> **$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');**

So you need to modify your AJAX handling method to keep the items you need.

Comment: Indeed, I misunderstood your question. Have you modified/extended the CI Session library in any way?